# Documentation for creating Mock object

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, mocking

I want to unit test wcf application. But I am not getting adequate information for Dependency injection and creating mock object. Can any one please suggest me something?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at [nSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com/).  It's a mocking framework that is in my mind a lot easier to understand than some of the others out there.
And [here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) is some detail on dependency injection.
Hope this helps you get started.

Answer (score 0):

Basic dependency injection is not a hard concept to grasp. You need to do these steps:

1. Create an abstract class or, preferably, an interface.
2. Create a class that implements that interface.
3. Inject the interface on the constructor's class that depends on it.

For example:

```
public interface IMyRepository
{
   void SaveData();
}

public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
   public void SaveData()
   {
      //...Do Something
   }
}

public class MyDomainService
{
   private readonly IMyRepository _repository;

   public MyDomainService(IMyRepository repository)
   {
      _repository = repository;
   }

   public void SaveNewEntityInDatabase()
   {
      //... Do Something

      _repository.SaveData();
   }
}
```

By doing that you have effectively injected the IMyRepositoryDependency into the MyDomainService class so now you can mock or stub it using your favorite mocking framework or writing your own.

For the first part of your question regarding WCF there are a lot of ways I could interpret this question so you would have to be more specific to get better help.

If what you want to do is to actually test the WCF services I would recommend that you only use those as a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) for your application so you will not need to actually test the services but the domain objects of your business layer.

For example:

```
public class MyWCFService
{
   public void SaveNewEntityInDatabase()
   {
      var myDomainBusinessService = new MyDomainBusinessService();
      myDomainBusinessService.SaveNewEntityInDatabase();
   }
}

public class MyDomainBusinessService
{
    public void SaveNewEntityInDatabase()
    {
        //...Do Something
    }
}
```

There is a lot more information I could give you but, again I'm not entirely sure what is exactly what you need. I skipped the dependency injection demonstration on the WCF part to try to keep the example simple.

Hope this helps.